# IndexError: string index out of range уже 3 день мучаюсь

Tags: python, python-3.x, update

Недавно столкнулся с ошибкой описаной выше, в заголовке. Решил написать (немного переписать код с англоязычной версии этого сайта) простой кусок кода который бы проверял наличие обновления, но что то пошлно не так...
Код предоставлен ниже:

```
versionSource = relver
updateSource = requests.get('https://pastebin.com/raw/6jGNkphP').text

for i in range(0,20):
    if updateSource[i] != versionSource[i]:
        updver = updateSource
        ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, f"There is an update available!\nYour version: {relver}\nUpdate server's version: {updver}", "UPDATE INFORMER", ICON_INFO)
        update = True
        break
if update == False:
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "You are already running the most up to date version.", "UPDATE INFORMER", ICON_INFO)
    pass
```

Comment: Уж про три дня то не надо завирать... Почему ты думаешь, что в updateSource как минимум 20 элементов? Или в versionSource как минимум 20 символов (судя по всему, что это строка)?

Comment: может в цикле просто поставить в скобках (len(updateSource))

Comment: А почему нельзя просто проверить `updateSource != versionSource`? Покажите прямо в вопросе, как выглядят  `updateSource` и `versionSource`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так вот этой ошибки точно не будет:

```
versionSource = relver
updateSource = requests.get('https://pastebin.com/raw/6jGNkphP').text

for i in range(0,len(updateSource)):
    if updateSource[i] != versionSource[i]:
        updver = updateSource
        ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, f"There is an update available!\nYour version: {relver}\nUpdate server's version: {updver}", "UPDATE INFORMER", ICON_INFO)
        update = True
        break
if update == False:
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "You are already running the most up to date version.", "UPDATE INFORMER", ICON_INFO)
    pass
```

Comment: Точно ли? А если versionSource короче?